# Is there a method to loop when adding more objects?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: 3D view]

[image: node layout]

[image: group]

I am learning how vectors work in geometry nodes, and this simple example scales a vector to place a cube between 0,0,0 and the position of an empty.

I created a group of nodes, so that I could replicate this effect with multiple cubes. However, this seems inefficient to me, so I'd like to know if there's a way to create a loop as we do in programming to add as many cubes as I like without having to manually duplicate my group node?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no loop node (yet) but you could e.g. this easy node setup to get what you want:

[image]

Comment: Ah instances and mesh line, of course thank you

Comment: As you said there was no loop node when I asked, is this what the repeat node would achieve now?

Comment: yes. the repeat zone is a loop.